Dynamic inputs to Date calendar CTE in Snowflake SQL
In Snowflake, how can I declare variables to make the this CTE calendar table dynamic?
The below works if I hardcode the start_date and day_count params, but I'd like to make it more dynamic.
SET '2020-01-01' = start_date
SET '2021-01-01' = end_date
SET day_count = @start_date - @end_date 


create temp table dummy_1(start_date date, end_date date, day_count int) as select $start_date::date, $end_date::date, datediff(day, $start_date::date,$end_date::date)

WITH T AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SEQ4()) AS num,
        DATEADD('day', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SEQ4()) - 1, @start_date)::DATE AS date
    FROM 
        TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => @day_count))
)
SELECT * 
FROM T


Maybe there's a cleaner approach, but putting the variable into a temp table and referencing the temp table in the csv seems to do the trick.

do I need write permissions to create a temp table?

I don't think so. In my company's Snowflake workspace I think I have the lowest of the low grants and can do it. Only one way to find out on your end. create create temp table dummy_1(start_date date, end_date date, day_count int) as select $start_date::date, $end_date::date, datediff(day, $start_date::date,$end_date::date);

I get this error
Cannot perform CREATE TEMPTABLE. This session does not have a current database. Call 'USE DATABASE', or use a qualified name

I think you need to select a database for your session. Either in the connection string, web interface breadcrumbs, or via SQL as mentioned in the error. But you don't need create table permission in that database to create a temp table, (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-temp-transient#creating-a-temporary-table)

hi I was able to figure out the database and schema arguments. How can I pull this all together?
I updated the question for where I am currently stuck

I'm not sure what you are trying to get as a goal - and the setting of variables is in the wrong order for at least one of them.

hi -- I'm beginner's level SQL knowledge. I'm trying to create a CTE of dates where I supply the beginning date and ending date to two seperate variables and the CTE can reference those variables to then create the rows of dates.

There may very well be a better way, but this is a way hinted at in the comments.
Snowflake generators don't seem to like variables.
SET start_date = '2020-01-01';
SET end_date = '2021-01-01';

create temp table dummy(start_date date, end_date date, day_count int) as
select $start_date::date, $end_date::date, datediff(day, $start_date::date,$end_date::date);

WITH T AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SEQ4()) AS num,
        DATEADD('day', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SEQ4()) - 1, (select max(start_date) from dummy)) AS date
    FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => ((select max(day_count) from dummy))))
)
SELECT * 
FROM T


thank you! where can I learn more about seq4(), generator() and dummy()?

@alejandro_hagan There's some documentation on the built-ins:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/seq1 , https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/generator . Dummy is just the name of the temp table, you could name it BlueberryWaffle and it's all the same.

thank you for your patience and kind words!

The generator function does accept session variables
set start_date = '2020-01-01'::date;
set end_date = '2021-01-01'::date;
set day_count = (select $end_date - $start_date); --use datediff if you wish

select $start_date + row_number() over ( order by 1) - 1 as calendar_dates       
from table(generator(rowcount => $day_count))

